# tomcat8: Unable to enter /manager/html

Tags: tomcat

This is my tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
                      version="1.0">

<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When I enter localhost:8080/manager/html in the browser, I get an input box asking me for a username and a password, I enter "admin" for both and click "Log in" and it just ignores my request.

Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, change your configuration become to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
                      version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
```